# why do drafts return as part of wp_query?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, post-status, tax-query

I have some code as plugin, which I call via AJAX from a page one the site. It gets two drop-down values and uses them in tax_query to fetch some posts. Question: why do **drafts** return amongst results by default? I need to uncomment `'post_status' => 'publish'` to prevent this from happening.

User is not logged in, and the doc says

> "Default value is 'publish', but if the user is logged in, 'private'
>   is added. And if the query is run in an admin context, protected
>   statuses are added too. By default protected statuses are 'future',
>   'draft' and 'pending'."

Does this mean that drafts considered "*public*" somehow? These are regular posts, no custom post type stuff here. Or is it tax_query overriding the default behaviour somehow? I'm puzzled.

Here is the code of query parameters:

```
  $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    //'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'height_category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( $_POST['height'] )
      ),
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'age_category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( $_POST['age'] )
      )
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is explained in the quote you've mentioned:

> "Default value is 'publish', but if the user is logged in, 'private' is added. **And if the query is run in an admin context**, protected statuses are added too. By default protected statuses are 'future', 'draft' and 'pending'."

Ajax call is always considered to be from an admin context.

Comment: Great, thank you. That 'admin context' part sure could have been explained better.

Comment: I've modified the Codex mentioning this partiular case.